# C# observer pattern message filtering

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm writing a video cms and want all my users to have new assets displayed immediately as they come in.
If I'm right, facebook updates its wall-page in realtime. So when I post something to a friend it immediately displays on his wall. The realtime web, as they say.
I wonder how you do that? Not the technology of client-server-communication, but what goes on on the server.
I understand the principles of the observer-pattern. 
But a wall is in fact a query on a table of messages. 
How does the observer know what query a user is interested in?
Does it hold all the query's of all connected users and reruns it when something new comes in.
I believe Google-realtime works that way to.
Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

When you open facebook, open the script timeline in your browser to see what scripts are executing on the page. You'll notice that there is a polling script being executed several times a second. So the page is looking at the cache several times a second to see if there is any new information that can be displayed.

http://www.ajaxwith.com/Poll-vs-Push-Technology.html - this should give you a background on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your suggestion is called polling, and causes a lot of unnescesary server and network overload. I was thinking about the server push technology. But I don't now what pattern to use when data is filtered at client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses AJAX and a JavaScript timer that polls in the background looking for anything that's changed. Other sites use the same type of functionality to update stock quotes embedded in the page, etc. It's not *truly* updating immediately, it's updating as frequently as the JavaScript timer hits their server. This is because web browsers use HTTP, which is a request/response protocol. A browser won't display anything that's not as a direct response to a request initiated by the browser; there's no way to just send content directly to the browser from your webserver.

Comment: Yes there is! You can use websockets. Ok, not all browsers support that, but my clients do ;-)

Comment: Ok, imagine that my clients all have a c# application running connected with let's say a wcf-service to a server. And I want to keep them up to date. Can this be done with the observer pattern, knowing that they don't have simple lists open, but searchresults etc.. ?

Comment: You would still have to poll. A WCF service doesn't push data, it returns data when a request is made. Technically you can keep a callback channel open with a very long timeout (I think the max is about 24 days) and send data across that, but in my experience that's not particularly reliable. If the server ever has a problem reaching your client, it closes the channel, but your client app doesn't know, and never attempts to re-initialize the connection.

Comment: My question is not about the technology of communicating between client and server. I will be using HTML5 websockets. And there is no polling involved in websockets. The server can decide at any time to send something to the client. My question is in fact about how to deal with it on the server. How can I keep for example a search result that a client has displayed up to date? What pattern should I use at server side?

Comment: Since WebSockets just sends raw data, it seems like the best fit would be the Command Pattern, where you would serialize your Command on the client, deserialize it on your server, and it would contain everything relevant to what the client wants to see. You would probably want to track on the client what you've requested so you can later unsubscribe, which would be a different Command that would need to be handled on the server side.

Comment: Thank you Joel, but what comes before the command pattern? Imagine a user (A) has requested a query that returns a list of assets. And a little bit later another user (B) produces an asset that should be in the query of user A. If i'm right i should use the observer pattern to send this update to all connected clients. But how does the observer know where to send it? Because not all users need the update because they have another query open?

Comment: Your WebSockets server has to track each connection separately; you could think of it sort of like a session on a normal webserver. Except instead of a session, you have an open WebSocket. You would have to do this anyways to write data to the socket.

Comment: @Joel C - Actually, a WCF service can push data by using a Full Duplex configuration (not all bindings support this, but it is do-able).  I've used this to update clients in a distributed application.

Comment: @RQDQ - yes, that's what I mentioned above with the callback channel. But the problem is error recovery; if the server ever encounters an error sending a message on the callback channel, it closes the channel. Depending on the cause, the client may or may not get notified, and if it doesn't, it thinks it's still connected, but nothing will ever come back from the server. So then what, you implement a Ping() back & forth just to make sure both ends are still connected? Now you're basically back to polling, albeit (probably) less frequently.